# C: how to check for user NULL input

Tags: c, null, user-input

I am building a traversable directory tree.

This is my code for the 'cd' shell command.

cd directoryName - returns the directory with directoryName

cd - returns the root directory

cd .. - returns the parent directory of current directory

How do you check for NULL user input for returning the root directory?

```
if (strcmp(arg, "") == 0) {
    return root;
}
```

Seems to throw a segmentation fault when you press 'cd'!

```
// *checks whether cwd has a subdirectory named arg
// *if yes, the function returns the corresponding tree node (and become new working directory)
// *if no, prints an error message
// *handle cd and cd ..
struct tree_node *do_cd(struct tree_node *cwd, struct tree_node *root, char *arg) {

    // initialising subDir to cwd's first child
    struct list_node *subDir = cwd -> first_child;

    // initialising parDir to cwd's parent
    struct tree_node *parDir = cwd -> parent;

    if (parDir != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(arg, "..") == 0) {
            cwd = parDir;
            printf("Returning to parent directory.\n");
            return cwd;
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(arg, ".") == 0) {
        return cwd;
    }

    if (strcmp(arg, "") == 0) {
        return root;
    }

    // checks if cwd has a subdirectory named arg
    while (subDir != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(subDir -> tree -> string_buffer, arg) == 0) {
            printf("Subdirectory exists: Entering!\n");
            cwd = subDir-> tree;
            printf("Making subdirectory current working directory: name = %s\n", arg);
            printf("Returning current working directory: %s.\n", arg);
            return cwd;
        }
        //else if (strcmp(arg, "") == 0) {
        //    printf("Returning to root directory.\n");
        //    return root;
        //}
        subDir = subDir-> next;
    }

    printf("Directory does not exist!\n");
    return cwd;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your `do_cd` function gets called with a `NULL` arg parameter, hence the `SIGSEGV`. A check against this should do the trick:

```
if (arg == NULL || !strcmp(arg, ""))
   return root;
```

I don't know your parser's implementation, but I can guess that it will (probably) never call your `do_cd` function with an empty string(`""`) for arg.

Comment: if (arg == NULL || !strcmp(arg, ""))
   return root; doesn't work

Comment: I don't think I null terminated my arg input, I might do that. Is it just adding \0 to the end?

Comment: Yes, strcmp requires a NULL terminated string. It is often a good practice to know your string length, so you can use strncmp instead of strcmp. If you know the length, you can just do arg[len] = 0; len++;

Comment: I think my argument is strsep (string separated) so it's like this: mkdir_hello, argument = hello, and it will not handle for 'mkdir' alone since mkdir_ would be the case for arg = ""

Comment: Great. It's usually a great practice on SO to say what you did to solve the problem.